# Updating Solr configuration to search on all fields

Tags: php, solr

Can anyone advise me on how to search Solr on all fields?

This is my current requestHandler called "search" and using solr.SearchHandler.

```
<requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
  <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
    -->
   <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

It appears that I can search on all *textual* fields, however I need to search on a field called 's_number' and this is an integer.

Do I need to use DisMax to allow for searching on *all* fields?

Also, do I need to adjust the defaultSearchField in schema.xml? It is currently:

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

Comment: When they are not text fields, they are considered facets and you have to do a faceted search: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview

Comment: @BenLee To perform a faceted search do I have to make changes to my solrconfig.xml in the requestHandler section to allow for faceting? I know that if I search for a textual term and _then_ filter down on the s_number then it works. However I want to just search on the s_number without the textual term. All the facet.field and facet.query entries are commented out in solrconfig.xml at the moment. Can you advise if I need to change this?

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question at first. You don't need facets here. Please see the answer I just posted for how to do a search on just a single non-textual field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search on non-textual fields you probably don't have to edit the config files. You just need to add the parameter correctly to your solr query.

The basic idea is you can use key/value pairs to search on non-textual fields. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax.

To search on just s_number, you'd set up your query to the solr server like this:

```
q=s_number:123
```

This will return only results where s_number is 123, as expected -- and it does it as a regular search, not a post-search filter. I don't know what php solr library you're using, so I can't give you the exact code for how to set up this query parameter in your code. If you tell me what library you are using and/or post the source code that actually does the search, I might be able to give you more precise details.

But talking directly to your solr server, the query would look something like this:

```
http://your-solr-server:8983/solr/select/?q=s_number%3A123
```

Answer (score 4):

The `defaultSearchField` parameter you're talking about references this field in your schema.xml:

```
<!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField further on in this schema  -->
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

If you look a little further down you should see statements that look like this:

```
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="summary" dest="text"/>
```

What you probably want to do is add a copyfield parameter for your `s_number` field, like so:

```
<copyField source="s_number" dest="text"/>
```

This will copy the number field into your default search field (text). The text field is a "dumping ground" of terms for a default search. The good thing about it is you can control how and what information gets put into default search. The bad thing is that you need to add copyField parameters for each field you want in the default.

Comment: That's really strange, all my copyField nodes are commented out. What does that means in terms of the fields that are currently searched? I can search on "product_name", however this is not explictly listed here. Does it make any difference that I am using Solarium?

Comment: Solarium shouldn't matter... can you post the PHP code that executes the search request? Are you searching on that field explicitly in your query?